# Adding string to embedded resources file stops project from compiling

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, embedded-resource

A resources file is compiled as an embedded resource in Project1. Strings are accessed code by:

```
Resources.ResourcesFileName.ResourceManager.GetString("Resource1");
```

Project1 compiles and works fine. I cleaned before building to confirm.

When I add another string to the resource, (TFS checks out the file) Project1 no longer compiles.

> 'ResourcesFileName' is not a member of 'Resources'.

How can I get this to compile again with the additional resource string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone must have changed the Custom Tool Namespace (Select resource file -> Properties -> Custom Tool Namespace) from My.Resources to Resources.

This generates a class and file ResourcesFileName.Designer.cs file with a namespace of Resources.

They then checked in the resource file and the designer file. However, somehow they checked in the csproj without the correct customtoolnamespace:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\ResourceFileName.resx">
  <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>ResourceFileName.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>**
</EmbeddedResource>
```